# O que significa Assets?

Tags: aplicação-web, terminologia

Trabalho há muito tempo com *frameworks* MVC em PHP, tais como Symfony, Laravel e Codeigniter.

Geralmente, quando se trata da estrutura de *views*, sempre há funcionalidades para facilitar a inclusão de arquivos como CSS e Javascript. Geralmente, são funções ou classes chamada *assets* que fazem esse trabalho.

Embora tenha entendido quais são as funcionaldades dessa funções, eu não entendo o significado da palavra *assets*. Eu traduzi essa palavra no Google Translate e o resultado foi "**ativos**".

Gostaria de saber se essa palavra *assets* é um termo específico da estrutura MVC, ou da programação no geral.

Assets se trata de um padrão ou apenas um termo?

Comment: Esta pergunta quase poderia estar no SOpt e no PL ao mesmo tempo :)

Comment: [O que é Assets?](http://tableless.com.br/workflow-para-cuidar-dos-seus-assets/)

Comment: As pessoas que deram downvote poderiam deixar um esclarecimento para auxiliar a melhorar a pergunta? Existe algum problema com a minha pergunta?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O termo *asset* é apenas uma palavra utilizada com um "contexto" um pouco diferente do normal no inglês.

*Asset* significa: **ativo**.

Mas é uma referência de ativo relacionado à bens.

Veja:

- **Liquid assets can be sold more quickly**
  (Ativos líquidos podem ser vendidos mais rapidamente)
- **Assets held by the company in Asia** 
  (Ativos retidos pela empresa na Ásia)
- **The business disposed of all its capital assets** 
  (A empresa eliminou todos seus bens de capital)
- **He transferred all his assets into his wife's name** 
  (Ele transferiu todos os seus bens para o nome de sua mulher)
- **The courts can order a company's assets to be frozen** 
  (Os tribunais podem ordenar que os bens de uma empresa sejam congelados)

Em tecnologia a resposta se vem ao fato dos seus "*assets*" serem os recursos do seu projeto. O seu "banco" de bibliotecas.

No caso pode-se dizer que o termo é mais uma adaptação da palavra do contexto do inglês para os projetos em si.

Pode complementar sua leitura com este [link](http://tableless.com.br/workflow-para-cuidar-dos-seus-assets/).

Answer (score 4):

Asset é um ativo, é um bem. Mesmo em software ele é assim. Asset é usado para designar itens que alguma entidade possui. Um bem não precisa ser tangível, então a tradução literal sem contexto já cabe quando falamos de software.

Claro que podemos definir melhor o que é um *asset* quando usamos no contexto de software. E pode ter até contextos mais específicos como o de um projeto, que pode ser de software, mas parece que não é o que deseja saber. Também pode ser uado em TI de forma geral no sentido mais normal de bens de uma corporação.

No software em si um *asset* é um recurso, é um item necessário para que o software funcione.

Um executável pode ser um *asset*. Mas geralmente usa-se mais o termo para penduricalhos que vão em volta dele. Podem ser arquivos necessários para o funcionamento da aplicação. E vão junto com ela para fazer o *deploy* (que pode ser uma instalação).

Em projetos mais soltos, especialmente web, o termo é muito usado e podem ser as imagens, e outros arquivos. É comum ver as pessoas tratando alguns tipos de arquivo como não sendo *assets*, mas estritamente eles são.

O que verá em projetos web é que alguns tipos são classificados assim e podem estar em uma pasta com esse nome. Nenhum problema usar o termo de forma um pouco variada, desde que todo mundo entenda assim. Então no contexto da pergunta um *asset* é um arquivo adicional aos arquivos que são consideramos principais do conteúdo, que pode ser HTML puro ou que sejam processados por alguma linguagem, como o PHP por exemplo, e gere o HTML final. Nesses casos não é incomum que até as imagens não entrem como *assets*. Portanto o termo pode ser sido usado para indicar que é algo que não seja o conteúdo principal de texto e imagens. E de fato ele é usado basicamente no contexto de *views*.

Ele é só um termo e não está vinculado a nada especificamente. Nunca vi algo que diz que o MVC tenha que ter *assets*, ele fala da relação dos seus componentes principais indicados pela sigla. E aí temos que fazer uma distinção do MVC web que as pessoas usam que é algo diferente do MVCV original, mas é outro assunto. Você pode fazer MVC sem *assets* explícitos, embora eles estejam lá de alguma forma.

Alguns *frameworks* incorporaram o termo para organizar sua estrutura básica, conforme citado na pergunta. Poderiam ter usado outro termo ou organizado de outra forma que funcionaria do mesmo jeito.

É só um nome que alguém deu para alguns arquivos para facilitar a comunicação, não é algo tão relevante assim. E pode ter significados ligeiramente diferentes dependendo de quem fala. Eu entendo que tem alguma vantagem, mas acho ela dispensável na forma que costumam usar. Poderia ser melhor em projetos muito complexos. Espera, MVC só deveria ser usado em projetos muito complexos... :)